# Django получить последнее уникальные значения

Tags: python, django, django-orm

У меня есть курс для пользователей, в который входит задача Item. И пользователи добавляют решения Solution. Один пользователь может создать много решений одной и той же задачи

```
class Solution(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
     item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item')
```

Как мне получить только последнее решение пользователя?
Я делаю так:

```
s = Solution.objects.filter(user=user, item__isnull=False).distinct('item')
```

Получаю уникальные решения, но не последние, а рандомные.
Есть поле timestamp но как его использовать? или как то по id?

Answer (score 0):

используя distinct вы получаете записи с уникальным значением 'item'без упорядочивания

Всем записям при создании устанавливается уникальный id, увеличивающийся от записи к записи, поэтому

```
s = Solution.objects.filter(user=user, item__isnull=False).distinct('item').order_by('-id')[0]
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Comment: такую ошибку получаю

Comment: даже если поставить .distinct('item').order_by('item', '-id')[0]

Comment: а если наоборот .order_by('item', '-id').distinct('item')